# Hebian learning rule in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

Sorry for my ignorance, this is my first attempt with tensorflow. For the k-th input sample [image: equation], and a learning rate [image: equation], I am trying to implement the Hebian learning rule given by,

> [image: equation]

where [image: equation] using tensorflow. 
After some search I found this [code](https://github.com/Neoanarika/Implementing-the-PowerSign-and-AddSign-rule/blob/master/tensorflow/powersign.py#L83) that implements a variant of the gradient update rule. In this code, the update rule does not depend on the input data. Could you please provide some hint on how to adjust the this code (possibly `_apply_dense` and `_create_slots`) to implement the above learning rule?

Thank you.

Comment: What is `x`? Is it input?

Comment: @Vlad thanks for the response. Yes, an input, I made an edit on the post.

Comment: Were you able to understand my answer? Note that you don't have to subclass from `tf.train.Optimizer` to implement it.

Comment: @Vlad thanks for the answer, please give me a little more to make some notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go with example. Suppose the dimension of `x` is `(None, 2)` and you're feeding batch size 4, so the dimension of `x` would be `(4, 2)`. Let's also assume that the shape of weight `w` is `(2, 2)`.

1. First we multiply `y=W^Tx` and we will have to transpose `x` as well to be able to do that: `y = tf.matmul(tf.transpose(w), tf.transpose(x))`. This will result in shape `(2, 2)x(2, 4)-->(2, 4)`.
2. Then we multiply `xy^T`. Here, we will also transpose `x`: `xyT = tf.matmul(tf.tranpose(x), tf.transpose(y))` which will result in shape `(2, 4)x(4, 2)--> (2, 2)`.
3. Then we evaluate `WW^T` which will have the shape `(2, 2)`.
4. Now we subtract `alpha*(I-WW^T)` which will also have shape `(2, 2)`.
5. We multiply what we received in (4) by `xy^T`.
6. Finally we update the weights.

The code:

```py
def hebian_update(x, alpha=0.01):
    with x.graph.as_default():
        weights = tf.trainable_variables()
        # 1
        y = [tf.matmul(tf.transpose(w), tf.transpose(x)) for w in weights] # y = W^Tx
        # 2
        xyT = [tf.matmul(tf.transpose(x), tf.transpose(w)) for w in y] # xy^T
        # 3
        wwT = [tf.matmul(w, tf.transpose(w)) for w in weights] # WW^T

        wwTshapes = [w.get_shape().as_list() for w in wwT] # shapes of WW^T 

        # 4
        diffs = [alpha*(tf.eye(num_rows=s[0], num_columns=s[1]) - w)
                 for w, s in zip(wwT, wwTshapes)] # alpha*(I-WW^T)
        # 5
        diffs = [tf.matmul(d, w) for d, w in zip(diffs, xyT)] # alpha*(I-WW^T)xy^T
        # 6
        update_ops = [tf.assign(w, w + d) for w, d in zip(weights, diffs)]

        return tf.group(update_ops)
```

Let's test it with small neural net on blobs dataset:

```py
# dataset for illustration
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
x_train, y_train = make_blobs(n_samples=4,
                              n_features=2,
                              centers=[[1, 1], [-1, -1]],
                              cluster_std=0.5)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None])

with tf.name_scope('network'):
    fc1 = tf.layers.dense(x, units=2, use_bias=False)
    logits = tf.layers.dense(fc1, units=2, use_bias=False)

hebian_op = hebian_update(x)

with tf.name_scope('loss'):
    xentropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=logits)
    loss_fn = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(loss_fn.eval({x:x_train, y:y_train})) # 0.14356796
    _ = sess.run(hebian_op, feed_dict={x:x_train})
    print(loss_fn.eval({x:x_train, y:y_train})) # 0.3619529
```

That is your responsibility now that all weights in the neural net are compatible with input `x` (i.e. to do `y = tf.matmul(tf.transpose(w), tf.transpose(x))`)!

Comment: Thanks again. I think I have a few questions. 1)  Why do you use to compute itteratively the basic computaions? I it possible to elaborate a litle more in this part? 2) In the test phase, why do you use twice the `tf.layer.dense`

Comment: (1, 2) I used twice `tf.layers.dense()` just to show you an example of network with more than one layer. I've never heard about Hebian update and I don't know whether it is used to optimize neural nets, so I showed you a generic case where the neural net can contain more than one weight matrices ( specifically, in my example is defined like this `w2^T(w1^Tx )`). If you would have one, two or more weight matrices the function that I provided is still going to work.

Comment: In case of `w2^T(w1^Tx)` I'm updating `w1` and `w2` independently, that's why I have updates as list comprehension - because first I'm updating `w1` and then `w2`.

Comment: If you have one layer (one weight matrix), the code is still going to work though.

Comment: So in the given example, there is a series of single hidden activation unit? Am I right?

Comment: You can say that. The `matmul` operation `w1^Tx` results in a hidden units (without activation in my case) which is the input to the second layer. The output of the second and last layer `w2^T(w1^Tx)`  is not considered to contain "hidden" units. In tensorflow the last layer is called logits.